# Is there a way to use a single class that does work on an array with two differently structured records?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I wish to read in from an input file and store the incoming data into an array of structs using class methods from ListClass. Which I have done. I then wish to read in from a separate file, that has a different format as the first, into a separate array but using the same ListClass. Is this possible?

I have tried using an abstract class but don't seem to get it quite right. for a small example:

```
 class ListClass 
 {           
     public struct struct1
     {
         public string strPart;
         public string strDescrip;
         public int intQty;
     }  

     public struct struct2
     {
         public string strPart;
         public char chrSold;
         public int intQtySold;
     }

     public int MAX_ELEMENTS = 4;

     //PRIVATE DATA MEMBERS
     private arr[] listArr;
     private int length;
     private int currPos;

     public ListClass()
     {
         length = 0;
         currPos = 0;
         listArr = new arr[MAX_ELEMENTS];
     }


     public ListClass(int size)
     {
         listArr = new Array[size];
     }


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Purpose:  Create a deep copy of the list
    //Pre:      List has been instantiated and orig contains list to be copied
    //Post:     An identical, deep copy of the list has been created.
    public ListClass(/*in*/ ListClass orig) //list to be copied
    {
        length = orig.length;
        //currPos = orig.currPos;

        // Allocate the new list
        listArr = new Array[MAX_ELEMENTS];

        // Copy over all the values
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTS; i++)
            listArr[i] = orig.listArr[i];
    }//end copy constructor


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Purpose:  Indicates whether or not the list is empty
    //Pre:      List has been instantiated
    //Post:     Returns true if list is empty and false, otherwise
    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return (length == 0);
    }//end IsEmpty


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Purpose:  Indicates whether or not the list is full
    //Pre:      List has been instantiated
    //Post:     Returns true if list is full and false, otherwise
    public bool IsFull()
    {
        return false;
    } //end IsFull


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Purpose:  Inserts item into the list
    //Pre:      List is not full
    //Post:     Item has been inserted at the end of the current list, length has 
    //          been modified 
    //Error Handling:
    //          if the key already exists within list, do not insert newItem and return false 
    //          if the list is full, do not insert the item and return false

    public void Insert(/*in*/ Array newItem)        //item to be added
    {
        // Make sure there is space
        if (NeedToExpand())
            //Expand if needed and insert new item
            Expand();

        listArr[length] = newItem;
        length++;
    } //end Insert


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Purpose:  Deletes an item from the list
    //Pre:      Method Find has been called to find the item to delete, and the 
    //          that item is in the list.CurrPos now points at the item to be deleted
    //Post:     The item denoted by currPos has been deleted from the list, lemgth has
    //          been updated.
    //Error Handling: If the list is empty, no changes are made
    public void Delete(string key)
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            Console.WriteLine("List is Empty");
        else
        {
            if(!Find(key))
                Console.WriteLine("Item not Found");
            else
            {
                if (length > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = currPos; i < length; i++)
                        listArr[i] = listArr[i + 1];

                    length--;
                }

                if (NeedToShrink())
                    Contract();
            }
        }
    }//end Delete


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Purpose:  Moves to the beginning of the list
    //Pre:      List has been instantiated
    //Post:     currPos has been set to the first position in the list
    public void FirstPosition()
    {
        currPos = 0;
    }//end FirstPosition


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Purpose:  Moves to the next element in the list
    //Pre:      List has been instantiated
    //Post:     currPos has been moved to the next position in the list
    //Error Handling: if currPos is already at the end of the list, currPos is not modified
    public void NextPosition()
    {
        if (!EndOfList())
            currPos++;
        else
            Console.WriteLine("End of List");
    } //end NextPosition


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Purpose:  Determines if currPos is at the end of the list
    //Pre:      List has been instantiated
    //Post:     Returns true if currPos is at the end of the list, and false, otherwise
    //          end-of-list denotes the first empty index in the list.

    public bool EndOfList()
    {
        return (currPos == length - 1);
    }//end EndOfList


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~        


    //Purpose:  Determines whether or not item is in the list
    //Pre:      item is assigned a value
    //Post:     If item is in the list then true is returned  and currPos contains
    //                the index of the item in the list, otherwise, 
    //                false is returned and currPos is at zero.
    public bool Find(/*in*/ string key)     // item to be found
    {
        bool found = false;
        currPos = 0;

        while (!found && currPos < length)
        {
            if (listArr[currPos] == key)
                found = true;
            else
                currPos++;
        }// End while

        if (!found)
            currPos = 0;

        return found;
    }//end Find


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Purpose:  Returns the current item in the list(denoted by currPos)
    //Pre:      List is not Empty
    //Post:     Returns the item at currPos
    //Error Handling: if Retrieve is called on an empty list an InvRec with a key set 
    //                  to int.MinValue is returned. 
    public object Retrieve()
    {
        object inv = new object();

        if (!IsEmpty())
            return listArr[currPos];
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The list is empty");
            return inv;
        }

    }//end Retrieve


    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Purpose: Clears the list
    //Pre: List has been instantiated
    //Post: List has been restored to its initial condition
    public void Clear()
    {
        currPos = 0;
        length = 0;
    }//end Clear

    //Purpose: indicates if the list needs to be expanded
    //Pre: insert must be called with a new item to insert
    //Post: returns true if length equals MAX_ELEMENTS, false otherwise
    private bool NeedToExpand()
    {
        if (length == MAX_ELEMENTS)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    //Purpose: indicates if the list needs to be shrunk
    //Pre: delete must be called with a item to delete
    //Post: returns true if length is 25% of MAX_ELEMENTS, false otherwise
    private bool NeedToShrink()
    {
        if ((float)MAX_ELEMENTS * 0.25f == length)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    //Purpose: to expand the space of the list
    //Pre: NeedToExpand must return true
    //Post: the size of the list is doubled
    private void Expand()
    {
        MAX_ELEMENTS *= 2;

        ListClass tempList = new ListClass(MAX_ELEMENTS);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            tempList.listArr[i] = listArr[i];

        listArr = tempList.listArr;
    }

    //Purpose: to contract the size of the list
    //Pre: NeedToContract must return true
    //Post: the size of the list is shrunk
    private void Contract()
    {
        if(MAX_ELEMENTS != 4)
        {
            MAX_ELEMENTS /= 2;

            ListClass tempList = new ListClass(MAX_ELEMENTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                tempList.listArr[i] = listArr[i];

            listArr = tempList.listArr;
        }            
    }
```

If the code snippet makes any sense. I have two differently formatted structs. That I would like to store into arrays with using all the methods in ListClass on each.

Comment: _using class methods from ListClass_ there aren't any methods here aside from your constructor

Comment: I can add them all.

Comment: Very unclear what you trying to do and what you have problem with... Code in the post seem to be some sort of re-implementation of `List<string>`... But you are asking about putting some structs into that... Just wild guess - are you asking how to make your class generic similar to regular `List<T>`? (starting with `ListClass<T> where T:struct`...)

Comment: Yeah I didn't really know how to put it into words. I have two input files with separate data structures. separately I can use ListClass to read in each file. What I want to do is have one instance of ListClass and use it for both input files. My only issue is that the structs have different structures. So I couldn't think of a way to make if work for both structs. Hope this is a better explanation.

Comment: My biggest issue is my private listArr. I can't figure out what datatype it needs.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well … given that this post is marked with the C# tag, I would suggest using an approach that is conventional for C#.

First comment, C# has a lot of collections built in, so conventionally one does not try to write them all over again. Another point, the types of Struct1 and Struct2 are different and it would seem that they have different meanings -- we could rename them perhaps InventoryAmount and SoldAmount.

So you just need to declare two lists in your main class, like this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
List<InventoryAmount> InventoryAmounts { get; } = new List<InventoryAmount>();
List<SoldAmount> SoldAmounts { get; } = new List<SoldAmount>();
```

Then you read in your arrays and just add them to the lists like so:

```
InventoryAmount[] inventoryAmounts = ...
this.InventoryAmounts.AddRange( inventoryAmounts); 

SoldAmount[] soldAmounts = …
this.SoldAmounts.AddRange( soldAmounts);
```

Actually this approach does a bit of extra memory allocation since the arrays are not used after they are added to the list. You could avoid this by putting each value directly into the list as it is read. Or you could just leave them in the arrays.

Another comment: methods like FirstPosition, NextPosition are more conventionally done using Enumerator and Enumerable. These are built in to the List class and arrays and are used by "foreach" like so:

```
foreach (InventoryAmount ia in this.InventoryAmounts) {
   ...
}

foreach (InventoryAmount ia in inventoryAmounts) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. But that's not really where my issue is. My issue is I can't use ListClass with both structs because my listArr doesn't hold the right format that could hold both structs. If that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comment, again I really wouldn't suggest carrying forward the ListClass code. You would be far better off leveraging the lists that are built into c#.

On the other hand if you really are determined to do it the hard way (i.e. probably the wrong way), then who am I to stop you?

Two of the prominent hard ways to do it would be either (a) declare a struct that could contain either an InventoryAmount or a SoldAmount, or (b) declare the array as object[] and use c# boxing. Both approaches are likely meaningless from a business point of view and are also inefficient.

For the first approach (a), just declare a joint struct for example like this:

```
public struct InventoryAmountOrSoldAmount 
{
    public InventoryAmountOrSoldAmount( InventoryAmount ia => this.InventoryAmount = ia;
    public InventoryAmountOrSoldAmount( SoldAmount sa => this.SoldAmount = sa;
   public InventoryAmount { get;}
   public SoldAmount { get;}
}
```

Then just use this as the type of your array:

```
private InventoryAmountOrSoldAmount[] listArr = new InventoryAmountOrSoldAmount[MAXELEMENTS];
```

Or the second approach (b) would be to declare the array like this:

```
private object[] listArr = new object[MAXELEMENTS];
```

Then you can assign each element of the array either an InventoryAmount or a SoldAmount. C# will box the struct by putting a copy on the heap and putting a pointer to it in the array element.